# XCode not saving location of entities on core data mapping tool

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data

It seems like every time I open the project the entities are stacked (visually) on top of each other. Has anyone else had this problem? Any clue how to fix it? It gets annoying when I have to drag >10 entities around to see their relationships.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have noticed this in the past. I stopped using the mapping tool for the models and just use the lists because of the annoying-nes of having to organize the relationships and entities every time i launch the application.

Comment: Yea, I guess it's time for me to start using the lists. I don't know whether to be more annoyed or feel better that it's not just me :)

Comment: It was really annoying when i switched from xcode 3 to 4. After 1 year of it, I guess i got used to it